# Infinite loop of evolutions with Play! framework and play-slick

Tags: playframework, slick, play-slick

After updating my web project which uses Slick and the H2 in-memory database to Play 2.6, I get an infinite loop of these messages:

> Database 'default' needs evolution! [An SQL script need to be run on your database.]

Clicking "Apply this script now!" runs the SQL and restarts the app - but the prompt is simply displayed again as if it had never been applied in the first place. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [described](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/6177b86f48ae477a7d2853b86d6eab6726149f2c/documentation/manual/working/commonGuide/database/Developing-with-the-H2-Database.md#prevent-in-memory-db-reset) in the official documentation, it is necessary to add `;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1` to the database connection URL, e.g.

`db.default.url = "jdbc:h2:mem:play;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1"`

Be sure to update `slick.dbs.default.db.url` too.

This prevents the database from being lost as soon as the application restarts after the evolution is applied.